# Get next time from array am/pm based on current time

Tags: php

I have array contain times in AM/PM format and want to get the next time based on the current time.

```
Array ( [main2] => 4:17 am [main3] => 5:39 am [main4] => 12:26 pm [main5] => 3:42 pm [main6] => 7:13 pm [main7] => 8:43 pm )
```

The current time is 7:14 PM, and it should return 8:43pm + "main7" key, based on the array above.

Comment: so if time 4:20am then u need index `1` did u tried anything for this ??

Comment: You can convert your values into a format that allows comparison, minute of the day for example, in that format, the first value will be `246`, the second `338`. Then you can find the value using something like this: `array.find(value => value > target)`

Comment: Why is this tagged with `javascript`?

Comment: For fine grained results, you could convert the time into a Date object or milliseconds and do your comparisons. But you haven't mentioned exactly which language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below:

```
<?php
    # get next key in arr
    function getNextKey($haystack, $needle)
    {
        $keys = array_keys($haystack);
        $pos = array_search($needle, $keys);

        if (isset($keys[$pos + 1])) {
            return $keys[$pos + 1];
        }

        return false;
    }

    $array = ['4:16 am', '5:38 am', '12:26 pm', '3:42 pm', '7:14 pm', '8:43 pm'];

    # your inputted time
    $time = '7.13 pm';
    # push into the array
    array_push($array, $time);

    # sort by time
    usort($array, function($a, $b) {return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);});

    # get the key and use it to get the next val in the array
    $timeKey = array_search($time, $array);
    $nextTime = $array[getNextKey($array, $timeKey)];

    # display
    print_r($nextTime);
```

Here we create a function to return the next key in the array, which we use to get the next time in the array. You could go one further and remove the inputted time from the array once we get the next value - but that's down to you.

Comment: Wouldn't this fail since `$time` which is `7.13 pm` is not a value in the array ? There is a `'7:14 pm'` but no `'7:13 pm'`.

Comment: @Titus that's what the array_push is for :)

Comment: Oh, I get it now, you're adding the `$time` to the array and then sort it.

Comment: @Titus yee :) then it's fairly straight-forward to just get the next val once it's sorted, only problem is OP expects to see 8:43pm when in reality, it is (logically) 7:14 pm as the next time after 7:13 (if that's the input)

Comment: Thanks, @treyBake this The best and smartest solution for my Q, you're legend thanks for being part of this community. 

could you explain this line to me?
usort($array, function($a, $b) {return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);});

Comment: @IbrahimHajjaj thank you ^.^ and sure, it sorts an array with a comparison function that turns the input strings into times, then it compares from there :)

Comment: thanks @treyBake , I'm asking because this function deletes keys from the array  which I need to display.
[main2] => 4:17 am [main3] => 5:39 am [main4] => 12:26 pm [main5] => 3:42 pm [main6] => 7:13 pm [main7] => 8:43 pm

I tried to use uasort function but the compares didn't work like f it ignores am/pm.

Comment: @IbrahimHajjaj does it need to maintain keys?

Comment: @treyBake I need to get the key for $nextTime variable.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much the same answer as treyBake but less complex (in my opinion).

Use array_search to find the time and return key+1 from the array.

```
$find = '7:14 pm';
$array = ['4:16 am', '5:38 am', '12:26 pm', '3:42 pm', '7:14 pm', '8:43 pm',];

$array[] = $find;
$array = array_unique($array); // if $find is duplicated then remove one of them

sort($array);
$result = $array[(array_search($find, $array)+1)];


var_dump($result); //8:43 pm
```

https://3v4l.org/uWtcF

Comment: this isn't really working if the input time 5:15 pm it'll input 5:38 am also it'll return Undefined offset if the input time is 8:43 pm. 

https://i.imgur.com/GPtTGwQ.png
https://i.imgur.com/CpX8UWR.png

thanks :)